# How to find the Average in a Calculated Member with filtered Values?

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx, average

I currently trying to Implement a Calculated Member (SSRS or SSAS ) which would Show me the Average Values per Customer, I need to divide the Sum of Values from all Projects, and divide it by the amount of Projects that don't have 0 as a Value.

A similar table of Values like the one I am using is shown below.

```
> Customer   | Project   |  Value      |
> Customer1  | Project1   | 124.24...  |
> Customer1  | Project2   |     0.00   |
> Customer1  | Project3   | 242.221... |
> Customer1  | Project3   | 72.221...  |
```

now what i tried to do in my Calculated Member is the following (i tried this in both SSRS and SSAS)

```
Sum([Measures].[Value]) /Count(Filter([Order].[Project], [Measures].[Value] > 0))
```

My hope was to filter out the Amount of Projects that have a Value of Zero, and divide the sum of Values only by the Amount of Projects that have a Value of <> 0.

the Problem is, when i get to the browser so I try my Calculated Member out the Count Value of Projects (relative to the ex. above) is 1 instead of 3,
and the Average value I get is :

> (124.24 + 0 + 242.221 + 72.221) / 1

as opposed to

> (124.24 + 0 + 242.221 + 72.221) / 3

(not devide by 4 because 1 project has the value of 0, and that's the one I want to exclude from the Count that I make).

Answer (score 0):

My question has been answered on the MSDN Forums by Duane Dicks, which I'm gonna post below.

" think why you are only getting 1 instead of 3 is because your filter is only looking at the all member and it should be looking at it's children.

Something like this should do it:

```
Sum([Measures].[Value]) /Count(Filter([Order].[Project].level(0).Children, [Measures].[Value] > 0))
```

"
[MSDN: How to find the Average in a Calculated Member with filtered Values?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/97365d8e-de96-4a05-9ab1-ce0cb8e93c66/how-to-find-the-average-in-a-calculated-member-with-filtered-values)